# Cannot view newly saved images in iis folder

Tags: image, iis, permissions

I have an application in IIS and there is a images folder where my uploaded images are stored.

I couldn't view these images earlier even in windows photo viewer (Error: "windows photo viewer can't open this picture because you don't have the correct permissions"). When i applied the permissions on the folder again i was able to view them.

But i can't view the new images which are saved into this folder. Everytime i have to set the permissions to view the new image.

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I suggest you could consider checking the folder permission by using advanced setting.

I guess the folder may have some inherited permission setting that don't allow your account to view the image.

Details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Right click the folder and click properties

2.Select security and select advanced.

[image]